# Can't put the output of two functions in a single row?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to combine two separate javascript functions' outputs but each function is on a separate line. I want them on the same line, once you see the page you will understand. I've been at this all day, but I can't figure it out.

I attempted to convert this to an external javascript file but it didn't work.

Comment: tuphotobooth.com/countdown2.php for the code

Comment: You mean you want the *output* of each function to be on the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want the *output* of each function on the same line, you need to change the container of the second function from a `div` to something like a `span`.

Change this:

```
<div id="cdcontainer"></div>
```

to this:

```
<span id="cdcontainer"></span>
```

Comment: OMG Thank you so much I feel so stupid that i wasted half a day trying to figure this out but thats how it always is.

Comment: @MarkValines: You're welcome. If my answer was helpful, consider voting it up. If it solved your problem, consider marking it as the "accepted solution". [You can read more here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @Colin, I don't think he knows how to "check" (accept) your answer...

Comment: Thank you derek for making me feel even more stupid i love the love oh wait @Derek